# scanf does not work in batch mode programming

Tags: c, linux

I am facing issue in my code it works perfectly fine when I try to execute in linux terminal in interactive mode shown here
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EbGD.jpg)

but when trying to do in batch mode I am getting an unexpected behaviour from program I do not know exactly is it the address like
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W14bN.jpg)

mydata.txt contains 7 2 as values for and b respectively

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a, b;
    printf("Enter Value of a, b ");
    scanf("%d %d", &a , &b);

  
    int temp = a;
    a = b;
    b = temp;
  
    printf("\nAfter Swapping: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
    return (0);

}
```

Comment: You're not checking the return value of `scanf`, so you don't know whether values were assigned to `a` and `b` before e.g. EOF of the input stream.

Comment: Does your mydata.txt file end with an end of line?

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of errors, copy and paste as text. What does your input file contain? Use `cat yourfile` to dump it to the screen.

Comment: issue resolved mydata.txt file  didnt end with end of file

Comment: but can you explain why without eof it behaves like the issue above

Comment: Perhaps there was something else wrong with your input file. It should work without an end of line character.

Comment: Microsoft used to put an actual character `0x1A` as end-of-filemarker for a text file, but typically, there is not such thing now. The `EOF` returned by C functions is a flag, not actual data. Open your text file `mydata.txt` in a text editor, and copy/paste its content into the question. Also, inspect your file with a byte viewer to see if there is any unexpected rogue non-printing character.

Comment: By definition, your file ends with end of file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem when using a UTF-8 file with byte order mark (BOM):

```
$ cat mydata.txt 
7 2
$ hexdump mydata.txt 
0000000 2037 0a32                              
0000004
$ ./a.out < mydata.txt 
Enter Value of a, b 
After Swapping: a = 2, b = 7
$ uconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 --add-signature -o mydata_sig.txt mydata.txt
$ cat mydata_sig.txt
7 2
$ hexdump mydata_sig.txt 
0000000 bbef 37bf 3220 000a                    
0000007
$ ./a.out < mydata_sig.txt
Enter Value of a, b 
After Swapping: a = 32765, b = 0
```

I think it would be good for you to do a hex dump on your input file to see if there are any strange characters in it.